# What is NURBS method?

Tags: modeling

I am modelling a series of objects which have mostly curves in them. I heard of a method to efficiently do this, the NURBS method. Is it efficient for making curve heavy models like archs or are there better options?

Comment: Have you tried using it in Blender ? What kind of model do you want to do ? Can that help : https://www.google.fr/webhp?hl=fr&ictx=2&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwirspjW_r3OAhVGfRoKHfRRBk4QPQgD#hl=fr&q=blender+nurbs+modeling ?

Comment: No I havent used it before. mostly arcs for architecture .

Comment: Please improve your question.  You might want to state concisely what you know about NURBS, demonstrating some basic research.  Otherwise it seems you want someone to implicitly do a web search for you.  You should also include some images of the work you have done in your question to show more effort.  You might be emphasizing NURBS as opposed to NURBS method in your question.  Please be clear.

Comment: Your last question is rather vague and broad.  [how do i efficiently make my models?].  I did not happen to give you a down vote.  I am just thinking about rational and unstated reasons another reader would.  This site BSE is not a tutorial site and your last question sounds like a request for a lengthy  tutorial.  Changing or deleting that last question would improve your entire question.

Comment: Sorry, it was a mistake. By "how do I efficiently make my models" i was referring to what method would be best to use in my project(spline modelling, poly modelling etc.)

Answer (score 6):

[NURBS stands for Non Uniform Rational Bezier Splines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_rational_B-spline) . They are a way of defining curves in 3D space through mathematical formulas.

NURBS surfaces are a method of 3D modeling using said curves to define object surfaces, as opposed to using a mesh based polygon subdivision method.

It works well with Boolean operations, trim surfaces, and intersections, and it's workflow is mostly based on defining loft curves and sections to build surfaces.

It is very precise and accurate method, mostly used for hard edge modeling objects with basic geometric shapes or flowing aerodynamic surfaces. It's often utilized in mechanics, or automotive design, aircraft or boat conception mainly in CAD based software, not animation or 3D modelling like Blender.

Blender has basic NURBS support but it is a stub at this point, with incomplete functionality and barely usable at all. If you really need to use NURBS you are strongly advised to look into other software, as it currently stands it is not production ready.

The bad news is there are no good free or open source alternatives, you may look into [FreeCad](https://sourceforge.net/projects/free-cad/),  or [MoI](http://moi3d.com)  or [Rhino](https://www.rhino3d.com)  or [Catia](http://www.3ds.com/products-services/catia/)

[See here](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender+nurbs+modeling&tbm=vid) for some basic Blender NURBS tutorials

Comment: Thank you for the answer! NURBS modelling might open up many doors for me even if it is a stub in blender currently.