# Curvature combs/ curve and surface evaluation tools

Tags: modeling, nurbs-surface

I have just started learning about blender and came from the world of Alias Auto Studio.  As I try to play with the Nurbs curve tools, I couldn’t find any tools to help evaluate curve and connection quality.  I used to use tools like curvature combs to help gauge surface sections and curves in other 3D softwares, is there something similar in blender?  Realizing each software is designed with different philosophy, I am hoping to find some tools to soften my seemingly steep learning curve... Thanks all for reading and grateful for any inputs.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60883/what-is-nurbs-method/60886#60886

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/147371/19156

Answer (score 0):

last week I released this product on blender market, assets including curvature graph are for free. Guess it is what you're looking for

https://blendermarket.com/products/surface-diagnostics