# Object do a little jump with follow path animation when rendered

Tags: animation

Blender noob here.

I'm trying to do an animation where the camera follows the path around the object.
When I see the animation in Blender, the path is flawless but when I render it, the object does a small jump.

My problem is neither at the beginning nor at the end. When is near the end, the object does a little jump, not when it ends.

How can I fix it?

The file:https://pasteall.org/blend/0f6db2fe965842028315f94808c07c3e

The video here:https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lotN.jpg

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: See "Paths" https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58709/what-are-the-practical-differences-between-beziers-nurbs-and-paths/58713#58713

Comment: My file:
https://pasteall.org/blend/0f6db2fe965842028315f94808c07c3e

Answer (score 5):

It is because frame 60 and 1 are the same. So these two same frames are causing the jump - just set end frame to 59 and you will get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaSqK.jpg

Comment: ...or dupe your keyframe to frame 61

Comment: @RobinBetts: or start frame to 2 :D

Comment: Hey guys!
My problem is neither at the beginning nor at the end. When is near the end, the object does a little jump, not when it ends

Comment: Then you should improve your question. And tell WHERE the jump is. Because it did jump at the end most…